# How to secure a password from being readable at the client?

Tags: php, javascript, xmpp, ejabberd

I need to pass username and password which is at the server to my web chat clients javascript function. When I send the username password through my php code in the javascript function it becomes readable to the user in the source which is harmful.

Please share your solutions.

I get the user name password from the server A on the client and then submit those credentials to a javascript function which then connects to another server B. Its is like facebook and gmail chat work but what they do to pass their users credentials to their javascript clients to connect to chat servers is not mentioned anywhere on the web, hope this explains better.

Comment: do you have access to server B?

Comment: Is this specifically for a chat server? Are you using XMPP? Is so perhaps you should mention it, since XMPP over HTTP usually performs HTTP tunneling through flash via strophe or something else. This changes the answers dramatically

Comment: @Salappy Yes I have an ejabberd server and a javascript client named ijab, its not about securing the data while on the wire its about securing it when its sent to the client

Comment: You should go for OAuth as explained in some answers below. If you have to handle the password in the browser in any way, then the user will have access to it. He may i.e. use the Live Http headers plugin in Firefox to watch every parameter you send from the browser to server B. It is not possible to prevent that.

Comment: There's too many unknowns, your question is really non-specific. "Exactly like facebook" tells us nothing, but fills us with guesses.

Comment: if you can provide encryption-decryption interface at server B then sure, you will be able to do it

Comment: There is no such thing as 'secure at the client', and if you think that you should send your password to the client in any form then your doing it wrong.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I assure you this is not how facebook and gtalk do it. Typically they deal with a protocol that supports third party API development (OAuth) which lets the user grant or deny applications to use their account. At no time does the client application know the credentials of the user. This is why OAuth is popular.

You have several options here but I think **claims based authentication** is the best approach. Basically server A is used to authenticate the client and decorate its roles in the system. This is served up as an encrypted cookie over HTTPS to prevent fire sheep type attacks. Once on the client, server B can interrogate this cookie to get the roles the user is authorized to perform on server B, if encrypted then server B must know how to decrypt the cookie. Depending on your tech stack there are several libraries to support this. Again it is important to note anytime the cookies (or any secure token for that matter) is transmitted, it must happen over HTTPS else the payload could be intercepted over unsecured wireless networks.

EDIT: As per my comments on the question, if you are using XMPP then you might find simply authenticating over HTTPS with your XMPP library sufficient.

Answer (score 13):

Don't do the validation in Javascript - do it in your PHP code.

Comment: your rigth in the validation context but my javascript function does not validate username ans pasword it passes the username and password to another server which is a chat server.

Comment: Why can't you use a post request to the chat server via curl from PHP to authenticate the user?

Comment: The function is a javascript client which will then communicate to the chat server so I need to pass the function the username and .password

Comment: -1 Because you don't appear to have tried to understand the context of the question and why the password needs to be passed via the client if at all.  You just gave a short and not very helpful rhetoric like response.

Comment: Client Side can be hacked because its on the client side

Comment: So how would you do it in PHP? Do you know how?

Comment: I do. Feel free to ask a separate question about it and someone will help you out if you don't know how.

Answer (score 8):

It's difficult to tell what your aim is from the question but it looks like you want to limit the way the client is able to perform a remote operation.

Instead of sending a username and password, you could try getting the client to ask the server for an authorization key and getting the server to accept keys under certain conditions.

You could then limit use of the key by:

- Checking the clients IP address and user agent
- Allowing the key to be used only once (e.g. store its use in a database)
- Allowing the key to be used within a time limit of when it was generated

**You should always assume any client side operations can be spoofed.**

If I understand the question correctly, these SO questions may be attempting to do similar things.

- [Passing untampered data from Flash app to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415/)
- [What is the best way to stop people hacking the PHP-based highscore table of a Flash game.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73947/)
- [Secure Online Highscore Lists for Non-Web Games](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999/)

Answer (score 4):

As long as you have to get the password on the browser, the user will be able to read it.
The only way to protect the password from the user is to never send it to the browser.

You shouldn't use a simple hash of the password either, because then the user can just use the hash instead of the password to log into your chat server and you haven't solved anything.

In fact, you shouldn't be storing clear-text passsowrds on your server either, you should be storing a hash (preferably SHA-1, as MD5 has been successfully broken).

You could instead

1. [chat server] generate a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce), save it and send it to the client
2. [client] send the nonce to the first server
3. [login server] send back to the client a (SHA-1) hash a of the password hash plus the nonce
4. [client] send the nonce and the hash back to the chat server
5. [chat server] check the nonce against your saved list and remove it to prevent replay attacks, then compute the hash again and check that it matches what you got from the client

Answer (score 3):

You don't need password to verify. You just need cryptographic hash of it. 
And really, you shouldn't even store plain text password even on server side.

send to client:

```
sha1(sprintf("%s%s",salt,hash_from_db))
```

verify at client:

```
sha1(sprintf("%s%s",salt, hash_func_as_on_srv(password))) == sha1_recieved_from_server
```

You can generate your salt form unique session id, remote IP or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

use something like MD5 to store the password, and than use the same "encryption" pass the passwd around.

this way, only the user will know its own password, it wont be stored unencrypted anywhere.

Comment: If i get the password In MD5 i will need to decode it on the client to pass it to the function, and sine the decode mechanism is on the client its useless

Comment: actually if you save the passwd encoded in the database, you wont need to decode it.

Comment: md5 is not secure, and this approach allows for replay attacks.  A nonce is required, at least.

Comment: md5 is not secure !? this is news for me... the only problem i see in this solution is be unable to discover the password. once you made the md5 you'll never get the password back.

so if the user requests to remember the passwd, you have to generate a new one and send by mail or something.

Comment: More about MD5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending (password and username) to server B retrived from server A, then if you want to make it secure, then you must provide some kind of security mechanism (interface) for that.

I would like you to have a look at [Two-way encryption: I need to store passwords that can be retrieved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089841/php-2-way-encryption-i-need-to-store-passwords-that-can-be-retrieved/5150459#5150459) question first. Here, you can store a `key` for **encrypting** certain `value` i.e. `username` and `password`.

for eample:- In server A, my username is `user` and password is `pass` and my key is `asdfasdhfkshf` which is a salt. In above solution, you can have two way encryption-decryption.

Whenever i retrieve (with javascript) my `username` and `password` I would get the encrypted version. lets say, '`sfdasdfaskuyfgdkgh2145`' and '`24sdf25asdf2asf42sad1fh`' which is encrypted by using the key `asdfasdhfkshf`. Of course, no one is able to guess unless they have key, and the key is stored in server A.

Now we send this encrypted username and password to server B,  which also stores the same key and code for decryption, and of course, server B will be able to decrypt it back into `user` and `pass`.

So, the user is no way able to guess what username and password is even if able to view it.

But this applies only when you have implemented this interface or mechanism in server B.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that happens in JavaScript is happening on the browser. That is the reason JavaScript is called Client side Language. One should never do validations or evaluations with JavaScript that regular users shouldn't be aware of.

Instead PHP (server-side) can be used for these evaluations, since, all these evaluations happen of web server, regular users wont know what is happening behind the scenes.

Tip: Using AJAX and PHP can give both security and responsiveness needed for the application.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could perform a ajax call, where you request the user/pass, just before you access the other server. In that way it wont show up in your JavaScript code.

Comment: It will still be visible to the user with Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

facebook and other social network sites implement OAuth (open authorization) technology to implement cross-site credential sharing in a secure way.
You may refer [this](http://oauth.net/documentation/getting-started/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Why actually you want it to store on the client side? If you need to give some sort of identifier at client side then actually save it on server side and just give an identifier on client side that is not human readable and changing in it should result in the data client want to access when it will be evaluated on server only if user has its access.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing will be sending thru PHP i think.

But you want to use JS specially so here are a few things i can offer;

Encode the password, md5(); if you dont think it is safe try multi layer encrypt like md5(sha1(sha1())) etc etc. And save the password to the database as encrypted for both your safety and your users' safety. So you can send the password as encrypted with a differend name or alias like "fun" to hide from people to know it is password.

Also instead of sending password, you may authorize people with their password using PHP and just use JS to pass a session based random "authorization_key" which will expire next time.

And also you can use Ajax. PHP with JS for those i told above.

Answer (score 0):

> (...) I get the user name password from the
>   server **A** (...)

It's sounds very bad that there's a *password server* in the system. Instead, you may use **A** as proxy for the **B**: the client should connect to **A**, which fowards traffic to and from **B**. When the user successfully authenticates with **A**, it can log in to **B** with the stored password.

Also, maybe it's a good idea to think over the whole setup.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not concerned with the security on the wire is it safe to assume you are not concerned with preventing the user getting the data using some other tool like fiddler/firebug or Wireshark?

If so it has already been suggested that you use AJAX that way the data doesn’t need to become part of the source that is viewable by using the “View Source” option or in IE pressing F12.

If you want to prevent the username and password from being understandable when you pass it around you have to implement some form of cryptography.  Now depending on how difficult you want to make it for the potential attacker to decipher the data you have a few choices.

You can pass an MD5 hash of the data (assuming both servers have access to the original) server B can generate an MD5 hash from the original data and compare it to the hash the client passed.  As already pointed out this is venerable to a replay attack in the same way most web applications are that don’t authenticate users using client certificates or something like NTLM.

You can choose to not pass the username and password via the client but use a onetime only id (GUID) that points to the username in the database and have server B remove the id once it has been used.  This way the data is kept secret and you avoid replay attacks. <- Not cryptography but a good solution.

There are also a host of other cryptographic techniques that you could research, but I think you want to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

javascript:function(){getAlementByTagName('password').value} past it in url

Answer (score 0):

PART I. 
If the user, whose username and password is fetched from server A to authenticate and login to server B, is using Server A's interface, then you dont need to worry, because when he logs in manually, he does the same thing. He writes the password in the password box and clicks on submit.

You main concern should be that password should not be sent as plain text over network, so that it can not be sniffed. Use SSL for communication.

PART II.
Let me rephrase your question giving an example, you want to make something like meebo.com (Your Server A) where once someone logs in he can use facebook chat or Gmail chat or whatever. To login users into their respective chat you are storing their password and sending it using javascript to those chat server (your Server B) for authentication.

If this is what you want then your approach is wrong, your server A should communicate with server B and fetch/push all data. Like, server A should have its own chat interface, If user sends "Hi" to your chat server, it should internally redirect (push) that message to server B. Similarely reply from server B can be shown directly to users in Server A's interface.
Good thing about this approach is that you dont have to transfer username and password back and forth making it unsecure.

PART III. 
One more thing I want to add, if you are storing username and password for server B in server A's database, then you must let user know of it in terms and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

you can create session at server side (using http-api) and transfer(session id,etc) it to client session

please refer http://metajack.im/2008/10/03/getting-attached-to-strophe/