# Securely sending POST vars from Flash

Tags: php, flash, security

I have developed a facebook application in which I am sending data from Flash to Php.

Its actually a game based on Flash 8 and at the end I send data by using

loadVarsNum()

using POST method to flash but the problem is this data can be easily tampered so I want know that how can I secure my data from theft or any hack

Is there a possible decoding method ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to stop people hacking the PHP-based highscore table of a Flash game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73947/what-is-the-best-way-to-stop-people-hacking-the-php-based-highscore-table-of-a-fl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out the references, and comments posted in this question: [Passing untampered data from Flash app to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415/passing-untampered-data-from-flash-app-to-server)

And/or this one:
[Secure communication between Flash and PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154844/secure-communication-between-flash-and-php-script).

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that you cannot protect Flash completely.  Because Flash executes on the client machine, your potential hacker has unlimited access to your SWF.  There are lots of things you can do to make it harder for them, but ultimately you cannot 100% secure Flash to PHP communication.  The best you can hope for it to make hacking your SWf more trouble than it's worth, and checking your data on the server for anomalies that would indicate tampered data.

There was a really good answer on a similar question here: [What is the best way to stop people hacking the PHP-based highscore table of a Flash game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73947/what-is-the-best-way-to-stop-people-hacking-the-php-based-highscore-table-of-a-fl/74841#74841)